# Sql query to get this result

Tags: mysql, select

Consider i have a `user` table and I have three columns `mobilePhone`,`homePhone` and `workPhone`...

I have to select `homePhone` for every user as first pref
 
if there is no value
 
   I'll go for `mobilePhone` and
 
   if there is no value for it
 
      I ll go for `workPhone`....

Any suggestion how it can be done in mysql..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using Sql Server [COALESCE (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx),

> Returns the first nonnull expression
>   among its arguments.

Same goes for MySql [COALESCE(value,...)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce)

> Returns the first non-NULL value in
>   the list, or NULL if there are no
>   non-NULL values.

Something like

```
SELECT  COALESCE(homePhone, mobilePhone, workPhone) ContactPhone
FROM    Users
```

Answer (score 3):

You want the `Coalesce` function which returns the first non-null value:

```
Select Coalesce(homephone, mobilephone, workphone) Phone
From `user`
```

Coalesce does exist in MySQL. It is an ANSI defined function.

[Coalesce function (MySQL).](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce)

Comment: @Thomas and @astander sorry in mysql

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT user, homePhone 
FROM user
WHERE homePhone != ''

UNION

SELECT user, mobilePhone 
FROM user
WHERE homePhone = '' AND mobilePhone != ''

UNION 

SELECT user, workPhone 
FROM user
WHERE homePhone = '' AND mobilePhone = ''
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested `IF` statements, or `CASE` or do this job using business logic layer

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use the following SQL:

```
ISNULL(ISNULL(HomePhone,MobilePhone),WorkPhone) AS Phone
```

Thanks,
Nirmal